# Test for multivariate stationarity

Tags: time-series, correlation, stationarity, garch, multivariate-distribution

Given a bivariate time series $(X_{1t}, X_{2t})$ with $X_{it}\sim N(0,1)$, I want to know if there is a way of testing if the bivariate distribution does not change over time. This is, if $F_{12}(x_1,x_2|\theta_t)$ is the bivariate distribution of the random vector, I want to test for $\theta_t = \theta$ for all $t$. For instance, if the bivariate distribution is normal, the hypothesis is equivalent to testing $\rho_t = \rho$ where $\rho_t = Corr(X_{1t},X_{2t})$.

The idea is to generalize the application to any random vector $\pmb{X}_t = (X_{1t},...,X_{nt})$ with joint distribution $F(\pmb{x}_t|\theta_t)$ and test $\theta_t = \theta$ assuming the the marginals are stationary, $F_i(x_i) = F_i(x_i|\theta)$ for all $i=1,...,n$. However, I think a constant covariance (or correlation) test might be a good start.

I have tried using the DCCtest function of the **rmgarch** package, which uses a CCC-GARCH fit and tests on the residuals, but I believe the test is not robust to deviations from normality.